# I've tried all the common ways of disabling css caching in Flask, and none of them work for me

Tags: flask, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I have an html file in `/templates/books.html`, which contains a
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename="css/style.css") }}">`

I have a file `static/css/style.css` with the following code:

```css
body {
}
```

so nothing in there. Then, I add one style:

```css
body {
display: none;
}
```

and it works as expected. But then I remove the style again, but Flask still keeps sending me the old file no matter how many times I change it etc.

I have tried the following, to no avail:

- Restarting the application
- Restarting my computer
- Adding something like `?v=1.0.0` to the end of the filename
- `app.config('SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT') = 0`
- Setting headers:

```py
@app.after_request
     def add_header(r):                              
         r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-
         r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"              
         r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
        r.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
         return r
```

- 'Disable caching' in chrome devtools
- Force reload with Ctrl + F5, Shift + F5, Ctrl + Shift + F5, etc. all the combinations, also tried just straight up clearing my entire cache
- Different browser, incognito mode, etc
- html meta tags:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Does anyone have an idea what else I should try?

Comment: how about restarting the application?

Comment: @Krishna ah sorry, I have indeed tried that too. I'll edit the question

Comment: And restrting my computer, that didn't help either.

Comment: The first step in figuring this out is to use the developer tools in the browser to look at the actual HTTP response for the linked file. That will tell you if it's being served from the cache, what the headers are, whether or not the file has actually changed, etc.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I checked the headers and everything seems fine to me: https://pastebin.com/ttybd05F.
The 'expires' time is the current time and is always equal to the current time whenever I refresh, whereas the 'last modified' time is from when I first put the
`display: none` in the file

Comment: That doesn't show that the file is being served from the cache. The developers tool display will show that. Either it is being served from the cache - in which case the question is why the headers aren't preventing that - or it isn't - in which case the question is why the changes you're making aren't affecting the response that is being served.

Comment: The devtools don't show it as being cached: https://i.imgur.com/0pTObB3.png
I believe if it was cached, it would say so in the size tab, right? Weirdly, if i uncheck the 'disable caching' box, it still doesnt say that its cached, but the size tab shows 243 B instead of 366 B. And I double checked that in both cases, even though the size is different it is indeed serving the same outdated file in both cases.

Comment: OK, so if it's not being cached then the problem is that your server isn't delivering the content you expect. So it has nothing to do with browsers, HTTP caching, meta tags, etc. You need to figure out why whatever is serving your static files isn't seeing the changes you're making. Maybe you're editing the wrong file? Maybe there's a build process that copies the files that needs to be run? There's not enough information here to help you with that.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry yeah i get you. Definitely not editing the wrong file, I double-and triple checked that. Thanks so much for helping me man! I'll try again to figure it out tomorrow, I won't bother you anymore. But you have been really helpful! Have a nice rest of your day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried troubleshooting by making a minimal flask project, and did not run into the same issue. Then I tried my original project again, and the issue as magically fixed. Not sure why, but I'll take it. I appreciate this means this question is not useful to anyone else, sorry about that.